# Getting dataframe column names with apply for graph title in R

Tags: r, dataframe, graph, apply, r-colnames

I run the apply function on a dataframe's columns and perform several operations including plotting some graphs. I want to get the column names to use them as title of each graph. I found a [post that uses lapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787534/accessing-lapply-column-names)  but I don't think I can use it since I need apply.

```
var1<-rnorm(100)
var2<-rnorm(100)
var3<-rnorm(100)  
df<-data.frame(var1,var2, var3)  
colnames(df)<-c("var1", "var2", "var3")  

myFUN<-function(x){  

  themean<-mean(x)  
  thevar<-var(x)  

  Name<-colnames(x)  
  thetitle <- paste('Variable: ', Name, '')  
  hist(x,main=thetitle)  

return(list(themean, thevar))  
}  

apply(df,2,myFUN)
```

Comment: Why do you need `apply`? Your `apply` call is equivalent to `lapply(df, myFUN)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mapply`, the multivariate version of `sapply`. But you would need to rewrite the function to accept two arguments.

```
myFUN2 <- function(x, Name){ 

  themean <- mean(x)  
  thevar <- var(x)  

  thetitle <- paste('Variable: ', Name, '')  
  hist(x, main = thetitle)  

  return(list(themean, thevar))  
}  

mapply(myFUN2, df, names(df))
mapply(myFUN2, df, names(df), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

The first call simplifies the output to a matrix. The second does not, it returns a list.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `lappy` such as:

```
myFUN<-function(x){  

  themean<-mean(df[[x]])  
  thevar<-var(df[[x]])  

  Name<-x  
  thetitle <- paste('Variable: ', Name, '')  
  hist(df[[x]],main=thetitle, xlab = Name)  

  return(list(themean, thevar))  
}  

lapply(names(df), myFUN)
```