# How to include function arguments in apply family?

Tags: r

I'm always bumping into the problem of wanting to use function's arguments into an `apply` function. I have looked around but I could not find any suitable answer...

**For example**

I have a simple matrix like

```
dput (tab)

> structure(c(108.13, 108.13, 107.7, 107.66, 107.65, NA, NA, 115.56, 
115.5, 115.45, NA, NA, NA, 122.72, 122.66, 124.81, 124.82, 124.87, 
124.91, 124.94, NA, NA, NA, NA, 130.18), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, NULL))
```

And I want to get the minimum of each column.

I would do something like:

```
apply (test, 2, min)
> 107.65     NA     NA 124.81     NA
```

But now let's say I want to skip the `NAs`.

For the first column, I would do

```
min (test[,1], min(na.rm = TRUE))
> 107.65
```

But I cannot use

```
apply (test, 2, min(na.rm = TRUE))
```

So, how am I supposed to pass arguments to a function inside `apply`?

Comment: `apply(test, 2, min, na.rm = T)` See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427253/passing-several-arguments-to-fun-of-lapply-and-others-apply

Answer (score -2):

We can use a vectorized `colMins` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
colMins(tab, na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

When we are not sure about  how to use the arguments, anonymous function call can be used

```
apply(test, 2, function(x) min(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or otherwise as @ahly suggested